# list of radiobuttons in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how I will be able to add radiobuttons to a list (like List (Of RadioButton)? Sorry I could not provide a code as I really don't know how to do it at all.. Searched a lot since yesterday but couldn't really find anything that helps

UPDATE: Sorry if I did not explain properly.. I'm working on Windows Forms. I am trying to create a single form with 5 textboxes (One for a question and 4 for possible answers) and 4 radio buttons to represent the four possible answers. I was able to do the list for the five textboxes with a lot of people's guidance and generous help but I don't know how to include the 4 radio buttons on a list

UPDATE: I used a list so I can go back and forth through records

Comment: ASP.NET or WinForms? In general you would rather bind a list of items to a repeating control than create a list of individual RadioButton controls.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  Context is important.

Comment: Why do you need a list at all?

Comment: I am currently working on a project (kind of like a quiz creator) and I want to be able to go through the records

Comment: There's nothing in that explanation that suggests a need for a `List(Of RadioButton)`.  I'm not even seeing a need for a `List(Of TextBox)`.  That said, you know how to create a generic `List` and add items to it then what's stopping you doing that with your `RadioButtons`. Either you're under some serious misconceptions or there's something important that you're not telling us.

Comment: What I did was a list of string, so I am a bit lost with controls

Comment: since you did a list(of string) for your questions, couldn't you do a list (of Boolean) for your answers?

Comment: Another approach could be to create your own object that holds the questions and the correct answer and populate your textboxes from it. Then it would be just a matter of storing the user's answer and comparing it with the answer the object holds. Would make it really easy to move among each one.

Comment: Hi @CharlesMay sorry but I am too inexperienced and not knowledgeable enough to be able to execute that :(